# How might I replace a portion of a link's href attribute with a variable value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following code, written using jQuery:

```
var strval = '22'
$("#quicknote").attr("href", 
  "javascript:location.href=/'http://site.com/notes/add?projects=/'+ strval")
```

Which results in the following attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:location.href='http://site.com/notes/add?projects='+'strval'"
   id="quicknote">
```

But, what I want is:

```
<a href="javascript:location.href='http://site.com/notes/add?projects='+'22'"
   id="quicknote">
```

Any jQuery wizards know how I might achieve this result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var strval = "22";
$("#quicknote").attr("href",
 "javascript:location.href='http://site.com/notes/add?projects=" + strval + "'");
```

Note the position and type of quotes.

On a side note, I'm not exactly sure why you wouldn't to do this instead:

```
var strval = "22";
$("#quicknote").attr("href",
  "http://site.com/notes/add?projects=" + strval + "'");
```

ie theres no need for Javascript in your example.

Lastly, since you are using jQuery anyway I wouldn't put Javascript in the href like this either. Instead add a `click()` handler:

```
$("#quicknote").click(function() {
  window.location = "http://site.com/notes/add?projects=22";
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score -3):

A JQUERY wizard tells you, that it is possible, but it has just nothing to do with jQuery, and that your answer is:

**You have the quote wrong!**

And there is no reason to vote me down, because I answered the initial question in very, very, very professional style.